# Dynamic table creation on button click in SQLite

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am creating a login application and I wanted to create a table for each user when they click the register button. The problem is, I am using their unique email id as table name. Later I learned that table names cannot have special characters like "@". Please suggest me a way to create table with names having special characters like "@". Or else, please suggest me a way to create tables with unique names for each user when they click the register button.

Please Note :"TABLE_NAME" in the code given below is another table containing registered user details.

The code is given below:

```
public boolean insertData(String name, String email, String mobile, String pass){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("create table "+email+"(Choice TEXT, Q1 INTEGER, Q2 INTEGER, Q3 INTEGER, Q4 INTEGER, Q5 INTEGER)");
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(NAME, name);
    cv.put(EMAIL, email);
    cv.put(MOBILE, mobile);
    cv.put(PASSWORD, pass);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,cv);
    db.close();
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, identifiers can be quoted with double quotes. Any double quotes inside the identifier must be doubled to escape them; and in Java strings, double quotes must be escaped with a backslash:

```java
String sqlTableName = "\"" + email.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";
db.execSql("CREATE TABLE " + sqlTableName + "...");
```

However, putting data into the table name is a bad idea, because it cannot be queried and modified like all your other data.

Better use a single table, and put that information into another column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Users(EMail TEXT, Choice TEXT, Q...);
```

Comment: What does this line of code actually do?

String sqlTableName = "\"" + email.replace("\"", "\"\"") + "\"";

I really cant follow.

Comment: It's basic Java, and I explained why it is needed. If you don't understand a particular operation in there, ask a new question.